# Duplicated CSS does not display the same

Tags: html, css, menu, accordion

This has been driving me crazy all morning, and throws away everything I thought I know about CSS.

I am using this following page to assist me in designing an accordion-menu;
http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu-css?s=1

Problem is, when I save that entire page, along with the associated .css and .js files, the menu displays differently. I uploaded the resulting display here; http://www.soflorealty.com/css/

I have no idea why (1) the arrows are doubled up, and (2) why the Heading are padded withing an already padded box.

What could be causing this even when the page is being saved completely as is, with no changes?
What can I do to correct the display?

```
    /* Accordion Menu powered by www.menucool.com */

/* ##### Top level items #####*/
#acdnmenu {
    /* Note about height: 
    Set "height:auto;" if flexible height is required. 
    A fixed height is prefered as content below the menu won't be pulled down/up when the menu is expanding/collapsing. */
    height: 300px;
    width: 240px;
    font-size:0;
}

#acdnmenu ul.top {
    padding-left:0;
    background:#484037;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#acdnmenu div.heading, #acdnmenu a.link {
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal 12px Verdana;
    color: #A98;
    background: #3A332C url(bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

#acdnmenu div.current, #acdnmenu div:hover, #acdnmenu a.link:hover, #acdnmenu div.current a.link {
    color:#CBA;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-decoration:none;   
}

/*Top level link without children*/
#acdnmenu a.current, #acdnmenu a.current:hover {
    color:#CBA;
    text-decoration:underline;   
}
/* arrow image for the top headings */
#acdnmenu div.arrowImage {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 9px;
    left: 8px; /* right:4px; or Changing it to "left:8px;" will position the arrow image to the left */
    background-image: url(arrows.gif);
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#acdnmenu div.current div.arrowImage {
    background-position:0 -12px;
}

#acdnmenu li.separator {
    border-top:1px solid #000;
    border-bottom:none; 
}


/* ##### Sub level items #####*/
#acdnmenu ul.sub {
    /* [disabled]padding-left:14px; */ /*This determines the hierarchical offset*/
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub div.heading {
    text-align:left;
    font:normal 12px Arial;
    padding:5px; padding-left:20px;
    color:#CCC;
    background:none; 
}
#acdnmenu ul.sub div.heading a {
    color:#CBA;
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub div.current {
    color:#F90;
    background:none; 
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub a.link {
    font:normal 11px Arial;
    color:#CBA;
    padding:5px; padding-left:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:none; 
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub a.link:hover, #acdnmenu ul.sub a.current, 
#acdnmenu ul.sub div.heading a:hover, #acdnmenu ul.sub div.heading a.current {
    color:#F90;
    text-decoration:underline;
    background:none; 
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub div.arrowImage {
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    top:6px;
    left:4px;
    background-image:url(arrows.gif);
    background-position:0 -24px;
}

#acdnmenu ul.sub div.current div.arrowImage {
    background-position:0 -36px;
}



/* ##### Followings usually don't need modification ###### */
/*Hack the font-size:0 bug for IE6 */
#acdnmenu,  #acdnmenu ul {
    display:block;
    font-size:0px;
    line-height:0px;
}
#acdnmenu li {font-size:12px; line-height:16px;}
#acdnmenu:after {content:'.';height:0;clear:both;display:block;visibility:hidden;} 

/*Hack for IE6-7*/
#acdnmenu ul, #acdnmenu li, #acdnmenu div.heading, #acdnmenu a.smLink, #acdnmenu div.description {*zoom:1;}
#acdnmenu li {*float:left;*width:100%;}

#acdnmenu ul {
    position:relative;/*!*/
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type: none;padding-left:10px;
}
#acdnmenu>ul{visibility: hidden;}
#acdnmenu li {padding:0;margin:0;}

#acdnmenu div.heading, #acdnmenu div.current
{
    position:relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#acdnmenu div.arrowImage {position:absolute; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: Without your code it will be hard to get a good answer. Please post your code or create a fiddle

Comment: I think you copied the "generated HTML" i.e. the HTML that was generated by the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the the problem is that you have a div with the class .heading and inside of that div is another div with the class .heading. This is a little bit strange from a structural standpoint. It becomes problematic because of the following css starting at line 19.

```
#acdnmenu div.heading {
padding: 8px;
padding-left: 24px;
text-align: left;
font: normal 12px Verdana;
color: #A98;
background: #3A332C url(../Accordion%20Menu%20CSS_files/bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

This will apply the arrow image and other styles to anything element with the .heading class inside of an element with the ID #acdnmenu. If you look at their example, they do not have an element with the .heading class inside a parent element with the .heading class. It looks to me if you just rework your html structure a little bit you should be okay. The alternative is less work, but not probably best practice.

Just replace the lines by line 19 with the following.

```
#acdnmenu div.heading div.heading, #acdnmenu a.link {
padding: 8px;
padding-left: 24px;
text-align: left;
font: normal 12px Verdana;
color: #A98;
background: #3A332C url(../Accordion%20Menu%20CSS_files/bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

Notice that I just tweaked the selector so that it only targets div.heading elements that are already within div.heading elements.

HTML Codes

```
<body>
<div id="acdnmenu" style="width: 240px; height: 390px; background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); border: medium none;">
    <ul class="top" style="padding-left: 0px; visibility: visible;">

        <li id="v_hm">
        <div class="heading"><div class="arrowImage"></div>Horizontal Menus</div>
            <ul style="height: 0px;" class="sub">
                <li><a style="display: block;" class="link" href="http://www.menucool.com/drop-down-menu">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
                <li><a style="display: block;" class="link" href="http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/tab-menu">Tab Menu</a></li>
            </ul></li>


        <li id="v_vm">
        <div class="heading current"><div class="arrowImage"></div>Vertical Menus</div>
            <ul style="height: 75px;" c="1" class="sub">
                <li><a style="display: block;" class="link" href="http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu">Accordion Menu</a></li>
                <li><a style="display: block;" class="link" href="http://www.menucool.com/vertical/vertical-menu">Vertical Menu</a></li>
            </ul></li>



    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like you are right about this.  When I changed "heading" to something else, it displays fine.  But I do not see the mistake of putting a "heading" class within another "heading" class.  Can you please point it out to me??

Comment: The problem is that you don't want all the styles of that header class to be applied. The way your CSS was written at the time of your original post it would apply for example that background arrow to both heading classes. Based on your HTML structure it is problematic because you did not want those styles to be replicated in both places if I am not mistaken.

which is why changing the selector here is also a solution. So before you had #acdnmenu div.heading, changing this to #acdnmenu div.heading div.heading makes it so the styles are only applied to the heading inside of another heading.

Comment: Hi Britton,  I understand the principles completely. However, if you take a look at the course-codes of; http://www.soflorealty.com/css/
I only see ONE "heading" class.
<div class="heading"><div class="arrowImage"></div>Horizontal Menus</div>

Where is the second one?

Comment: I have highlighted in an semi-transparent orange the two places where these come up. Are you familiar with the web inspector?  Checkout the link that I posted. 

http://postimg.org/image/c2bknprht/

Comment: Thank you for posting and highlighting those codes, but those are not the source codes in question.  Check this page out; http://www.soflorealty.com/css/

The problem in the same, but the "heading" WITHIN a "heading tag does not exist.  What do you make of that?

Comment: I have been looking at the link that you posted, and in the web inspector I can clearly see that they do exist. I have already highlighted where they are. Are you familiar with the web inspector? Feel free to post your html on here. And I would be happy to highlight for you there where you have an element with the class heading inside of an element class heading. 

Another way you can find this for yourself is if you just use search in your IDE for heading and it should highlight the places where this is in your code.

I am asking you about the web inspector because it is an invaluable tool.

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with web-inspector. Which is "Inspect Element (Q)" on Firefox.  Although I am no pro at it.  I've reduced the menu down to 2 options, for simplicity of inspecting the HTML, and posted them above.  Thanks for your patience!

Comment: It looks like your html does not match what they tell you do on their site. Review their html section, I believe the javascript file is add one of the heading class item. I reviewed the source html file of yours and compared it again the web inspector version and I can see that you have one heading element like you had been saying, but the web inspected version still has two. Which means that the javascript is adding one in. This is why we were both seeing different things. I was seeing the computed result, you were looking at your code. I can't verify this 100% since their JS is minified.

Comment: But, if you go back to their site and review the html that they require and make sure it matches yours you should be well on your way.

Comment: I understand.  The JS adding additional heading class must be what's happening.  I did not know JS could insert HTML.   Okay, just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy.  But I did work around the issues.  Thanks for your attention. - Noy Hadar

Comment: No problem, It would be good to mark what answered your question for someone who has the same problem in the future.